# How can I find the index where one list appears as a sublist of another?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, sublist

I have been working with Haskell for a little over a week now so I am practicing some functions that might be useful for something. I want to compare two lists recursively. When the first list appears in the second list, I simply want to return the index at where the list starts to match. The index would begin at 0. Here is an example of what I want to execute for clarification:

```
subList [1,2,3] [4,4,1,2,3,5,6]
```

the result should be 2

I have attempted to code it:

```
subList :: [a] -> [a] -> a
subList [] = []
subList (x:xs) = x + 1 (subList xs)
subList xs = [ y:zs | (y,ys) <- select xs, zs <- subList ys]
        where select []     = []
              select (x:xs) = x
```

I am receiving an "error on input" and I cannot figure out why my syntax is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: I get errors, but none of them say "error on input". Are you sure you pasted exactly the code you have? Have you tried making a file with *just* this code, to make sure the error is in this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first look at the function signature.  You want to take in two lists whose contents can be compared for equality and return an index like so

```
subList :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
```

So now we go through pattern matching on the arguments.  First off, when the second list is empty then there is nothing we can do, so we'll return -1 as an error condition

```
subList _ [] = -1
```

Then we look at the recursive step

```
subList as xxs@(x:xs)
  | all (uncurry (==)) $ zip as xxs = 0
  | otherwise                       = 1 + subList as xs
```

You should be familiar with the guard syntax I've used, although you may not be familiar with the `@` syntax.  Essentially it means that `xxs` is just a sub-in for if we had used `(x:xs)`.

You may not be familiar with `all`, `uncurry`, and possibly `zip` so let me elaborate on those more.  `zip` has the function signature `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]`, so it takes two lists and pairs up their elements (and if one list is longer than the other, it just chops off the excess).  `uncurry` is weird so lets just look at `(uncurry (==))`, its signature is `(uncurry (==)) :: Eq a => (a, a) -> Bool`, it essentially checks if both the first and second element in the pair are equal.  Finally, `all` will walk over the list and see if the first and second of each pair is equal and return true if that is the case.

Comment: after one week `all`, `uncurry` and `zip` might not be that obvious as well (maybe you should use `zipWith` and a lambda instead?) - but nice answer!

Comment: @CarstenKönig Good point, I'll edit it to explain that better then

Comment: @randomusername thanks for the explanation, I'm familiar with `zip` a little as I've been reading the "To Learn You A Haskell" book. However thanks for explaining the others to me.

Comment: @randomusername I am still a little confused on one thing, when using the '@' syntax I receive a parsing error for that symbol. Why is that?

Comment: @ExecutionStyle21 It could be that I've gotten the order mixed up, I can never remember which one it's supposed to be.  Try `xxs@(x:xs)`.

Comment: @randomusername yeah that is all it was! That is actually going to come in handy thank you so much for the information that clears up so much.

Comment: @ExecutionStyle21 I have edited it so it is in the correct order now.

Comment: Nice function! But only worked for me once I replaced `subList _ [] = -1` with `subList _ [] = minBound::Int` --- still hacky as it would fail the (probably impossible, in any event unrealistic) case of strings with length>maxBound::Int

Comment: My adaptation: maybe I messed something up? Pretty much the same though except for minBound (the smallest negative int possible) ---

`indexOfSub _ [] = minBound::Int ; indexOfSub sub str@(char:rest) | all (uncurry (==)) (zip sub str) = 0 | otherwise = 1+(indexOfSub sub rest)`

--- obviously you're counting back up from the final -1 all the way the length of the string so if you don't like minBound need a check on the-result-of-the-recursion in `otherwise`

Comment: Just for fun, here's a dirty "last index of sublist" using y/our above:

`lastIndexOfSub sub str = if idx<0 then -1 else (length str)-(length sub)-idx where idx = indexOfSub (reverse sub) (reverse str)`